# An internal error occurred during deploying app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot

I am a fresher & Currently working in java spring boot . I have converted my spring project to app engine project by adding libraries and plugins to **pom.xml**. But while trying to deploy this, I am getting corresponding error . I would be pleased if someone helps me to resolve this.

**The error is:**

> An internal error occurred during: "Deploying to App Engine".
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Could you provide logs ?

Comment: I assume you are deploying your application to the Google App Engine using the gcloud app deploy command. To review issues with deployment, providing the debug logs would always be helpful to determine the root cause of the deployment failure. Debug logs can be obtained by adding the [verbosity flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#SYNOPSIS), for instance using this command: gcloud app deploy --verbosity debug